# ZSH not displaying anything

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

just installed ZSH.
For some reason the only thing it's displaying is my `root`.
Even if I navigate to a different folder it's won't change. (Like even if my current path is on the Desktop it's won't show it). PLUS I don't have any syntax. (won't work either in terminal and iTerm2)
[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the prompt? Can you try `PS1='%~>'`

Comment: That is the name of your machine and it is not what is usually meant when using the term `root`. Usually `root` means either the directory `/` or the primary administrator account, which actually has the name "root". Also, what you are seeing is the the way the default prompt of Zsh looks like. If you want something more informative or colorful, you will have to modify the configuration (especially the `PROMPT` aka `PS1` parameter). Personally, I would suggest creating your own configuration step-by-step. But if you want *everything* and *now*, search for "prezto" or "oh-my-zsh"

Comment: you likely made a typo in your `~/.zshrc` file. Please attach it